# ACER F15 and NVIDIA drivers blank screen

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, xorg, opensuse

I'm on openSUSE Leap 42.1 and I'm trying to make it work with the NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

At the moment, with the drivers installed via `zypper` or without proprietary drivers, my laptop (Acer F15 with a NVIDIA Geo Force 940M) is almost useless.

It freezes almost always using both KDE, GNOME and also other desktop environments. It seems a video driver problem and because of this I'm trying to install the proprietary drivers manually.

I downloaded the latest version (Also tried others).

When I installed it, run `mkinitrd` and blacklisted `nouveau`. Now I get a blank screen.

The log files says: `xf86OpenConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Operation not permitted`

Tried to generate a new `xorg.conf` file via `nvidia-config` but nothing.

Tried `su - -c chmod 4755 /usr/bin/Xorg` but nothing also in this case.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

nvidia has official repository for its drivers:

http://http.download.nvidia.com/opensuse/leap/42.1

so correct way to install Nvidia drivers are :

1. add nvidia repo `zypper ar -f http://http.download.nvidia.com/opensuse/leap/42.1 nvidia`
2. `zypper in x11-video-nvidiaG04 nvidia-gfxG04-kmp-default nvidia-glG04`